# Displaying text in a NSScrollView (Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, nsscrollview, nsmutableattributedstring

Just started to learn Swift and created a little macOS app in which I want to use a `NSScrollView` to display an attributed String. I’ve tried:

```
@IBOutlet var ScrollViewOutlet : NSScrollView
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myText)
ScrollViewOutlet.insertText(attributedString)
```

But that doesn’t seem to work. Feels confusing since doing the exact same with a `NSTextView` instead works like a charm.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the earlier beta versions (which featured Swift) of Xcode had some serious issues with this kind of outlets (as you can see here: http://swiftwtf.tumblr.com/post/88387419568/nstextview). **However, since `Xcode 6 Beta 6` it works.**

```
textFieldOutlet.textStorage.mutableString.setString("Hello w0rld!")
```

To handle the String, creating an outlet for the `textField` instead of the `scrollView` itself is also a better practice.

Answer (score 15):

In the following example, I added the scrollView in the interface builder as my starting point.

The following works if you your scrollView/textView is empty/blank OR if you need to append text in front of what is already in the scrollView/textView.  If there is already text in the box, the new text is inserted in front of the existing text.

The documentView is an NSTextView

**Swift 4.0**

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageDestinationDirectory: NSScrollView!

...

let destinationText = "Text to display"
imageDestinationDirectory.documentView!.insertText(destinationText)
```

Answer (score 5):

Apple's has an article about setting up a text view inside a scroll view programmatically. [Text System User Interface Layer Programming Guide: Putting an NSTextView Object in an NSScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextUILayer/Tasks/TextInScrollView.html) You should read that for greatest understanding, but here's the code:

```
NSScrollView *scrollview = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[theWindow contentView] frame]];
NSSize contentSize = [scrollview contentSize];

[scrollview setBorderType:NSNoBorder];
[scrollview setHasVerticalScroller:YES];
[scrollview setHasHorizontalScroller:NO];
[scrollview setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable];

theTextView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, contentSize.width, contentSize.height)];
[theTextView setMinSize:NSMakeSize(0.0, contentSize.height)];
[theTextView setMaxSize:NSMakeSize(FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX)];
[theTextView setVerticallyResizable:YES];
[theTextView setHorizontallyResizable:NO];
[theTextView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable];

[[theTextView textContainer] setContainerSize:NSMakeSize(contentSize.width, FLT_MAX)];
[[theTextView textContainer] setWidthTracksTextView:YES];
[scrollview setDocumentView:theTextView];
[theWindow setContentView:scrollview];
[theWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
[theWindow makeFirstResponder:theTextView];
```

You can then set the text of the text view by operating on its `textStorage` object:

```
theTextView.textStorage.attributedString = attributedString;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to do it programmatically, with auto layout:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    let scrollView = NSScrollView()
    let textView = NSTextView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textView.maxSize = NSSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        textView.autoresizingMask = .width
        textView.isVerticallyResizable = true
        textView.textContainer?.widthTracksTextView = true

        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.documentView = textView

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: NSScrollView!
```

The `documentView` of the `NSScrollView` is an `NSTextView`, so in Swift you can use the following:

```
let textView : NSTextView? = scrollView?.documentView as? NSTextView
textView?.string = text
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work in Swift 5.5.2.  The textView is always nil.  This is trying to cast an NSView to an NSTextField, which fails.

Answer (score 2):

For NSScrollView:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textScroll: NSScrollView!
```

Check this out:

```
let text = textScroll.documentView!.textStorage!!
let attr = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello World")

text.appendAttributedString(attr)
```

This is very much in spirit of @mrtn.lxo solution, only done for NSScrollView and is using NSAttributedString.

Comment: The API must have changed because there is no textStorage in the documentView in Swift 5.5.2.

Answer (score 2):

answer of ixany worked great, but as a beginner it looks me more time to figure it out, that outlet should be done for NSTextView and not for NSTextScroll. NSTextView is hidden inside of NSTextScroll.
[All Results Field is NSTextScroll in my case and Text View Results is NSTextView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGDBp.png)